# Python: Pass a generic dictionary as a command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a script that needs to take in the name of a file and a set of key=value pairs.  The set of key=value pairs is not defined. They are dependent on the file that was passed in.

eg:

```
Script.py file1 bob=1 sue=2 ben=3  # file 1 needs bob, sue, and ben

Script.py file2 mel=1 gorge=3 steve=3 # file 2 needs mel, gorge, and steve
```

Is this possible with argparse / optparse or do I have to build my own parser?

Comment: Parsing this is around 5 lines of code.. does it really matter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That should be fairly easy to parse yourself. Use of the helper libraries would be complicated by not knowing the keys in advance. The filename is in sys.argv[1]. You can build the dictionary with a list of strings split with the '=' character as a delimiter.

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
args = dict([arg.split('=', maxsplit=1) for arg in sys.argv[2:]])
print filename
print args
```

Output:

```
$ Script.py file1 bob=1 sue=2 ben=3
file1
{'bob': '1', 'ben': '3', 'sue': '2'}
```

That's the gist of it, but you may need more robust parsing of the key-value pairs than just splitting the string. Also, make sure you have at least two arguments in `sys.argv` before trying to extract the filename.

Comment: simpler: `dict(arg.split('=') for arg in sys.argv[2:])`

Comment: Thanks for the clue,  I'm going to go with a combination:

`    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test dictionary as args')
    parser.add_argument("file")
    parser.add_argument("dictionary", nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args
    print args.dictionary
    print dict([x.split('=') for x in args.dictionary])
    print args.dictionary.__class__
`

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, that is better. I changed the answer.

Comment: This solution will only work as long as none of the keys or values contain '=' character.  Consider specifying maxsplit=1 to ensure you only get back two values when splitting each arg.  Not bullet-proof, but better than the provided solution as it stands.

Comment: @AJ That is exactly why I wrote that last paragraph. ;) Also, I added maxsplit as you suggested since that is a good and simple improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately maxsplit=1 will not work as split does not accept keyword for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, instead of passing a dict you can pass an "escaped" json string as a command line argument

```
import optparse
import json

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-t", "--test", dest="test", action="store", type="string")
options, _ = parser.parse_args()
my_dict = json.loads(options.test)
print my_dict['key1']
```

then use it as so:

```
python test.py -t "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

this will output "value1"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

## Example: 1:

```
# runline argument is : ./filename fname=sameer sname=ali age=29
import sys 

l = sys.argv[1:]

print(l)
```

l = ['fname=sameer', 'sname=ali', 'age=29']

```
for i in l:

    runarg = i.split('=')

    d[runarg[0]] = runarg[1]

print(d)

{'fname': 'sameer', 'sname': 'ali', 'age': '29'}
```

## Example: 2

print(sys.argv[1:]

```
ouput: ['fname=sameer', 'sname=ali', 'age=29']
```

newlist = [x.split('=') for x in l]
print(newlist)

```
output: [['fname', 'sameer'], ['sname', 'ali'], ['age', '29']]
```

newdict =  dict(newlist)

print(newdict)

```
output: {'fname': 'sameer', 'sname': 'ali', 'age': '29'}
```